# Where can I find interpolation formulas or tabulated data for phase diagram(s)?

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, phase-diagram, data

In order to program it, where can I find accurate representations of the water (or others - e.g.: CO2) phase diagrams, in the form of mathematical functions or in the form of interpolable tabulated data? (I'm not in this domain - just a hobbyist, and I have no specific institutional access)

Comment: Note to mods: Add CW post notice when bounty is gone.

Comment: Why did you change my question to Community Wiki ?

Comment: That is standard policy for res. recom. qs, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7039/2451) meta post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For water, the canonical source is

Wagner, W., & Pruß, A. (2002). The IAPWS formulation 1995 for the thermodynamic properties of ordinary water substance for general and scientific use. Journal of physical and chemical reference data, 31(2), 387-535.
[www.thermophysics.ru/pdf_doc/IAPWS_1995.pdf](http://www.thermophysics.ru/pdf_doc/IAPWS_1995.pdf)

For CO2, see, e.g.,

Wang, J., Jia, C. S., Li, C. J., Peng, X. L., Zhang, L. H., & Liu, J. Y. (2019). Thermodynamic properties for carbon dioxide. ACS omega, 4(21), 19193-19198.

Answer (score 3):

Perry's Chemical Engineering Handbook is full of tables and empirical equations for estimating physical properties of a variety of substances.

On line you can find reliable data in data banks such as:

Dortmund Data Bank: http://dortmunddatabank.com/

Korean Data Bank: https://cheric.org/research/kdb/

NIST Chemical Web Book: https://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/